# Joining a Query and sub-query

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I'm trying to join a query and a sub-query in Access but haven't the faintest idea on how to do that. Rather than saving the sub-query as a different query and then joining it to the main query.

Main query (with reference to sub-query):

```
SELECT tb200_IraDataIn.tb200_niarnum, tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IraAccDesc,
tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IraAccNum, tb15_Securities.tb15_IsActiveRegister,
tb15_Securities.tb15_NiarDesc, tb15_Securities.tb15_ManpikID, tb200_IraDataIn.tb200_Shovi, tb10_Afik.tb10_InvestTool, 
tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IsActive, tb200_IraDataIn.tb200_Shovi, 
tb200_IraDataIn.tb200_Shovi/SubQuery1.SumOftb200_Shovi AS Expr1
FROM SubQuery1 
     INNER JOIN (tb10_Afik 
         INNER JOIN (tb15_Securities 
           INNER JOIN (tb206_IraAccount 
              INNER JOIN tb200_IraDataIn 
              ON tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IraAccNum = tb200_IraDataIn.tb200_accountNumber) 
           ON tb15_Securities.tb15_NiarID = tb200_IraDataIn.tb200_niarnum) 
         ON (tb10_Afik.tb10_AfikID = tb200_IraDataIn.tb200_afik) AND (tb10_Afik.tb10_Erp =tb200_IraDataIn.tb200_ERP))
     ON SubQuery1.tb206_IraAccNum = tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IraAccNum
WHERE (((tb15_Securities.tb15_IsActiveRegister)=Yes) AND ((tb10_Afik.tb10_InvestTool)=1
Or (tb10_Afik.tb10_InvestTool)=4 Or (tb10_Afik.tb10_InvestTool)=21 Or 
(tb10_Afik.tb10_InvestTool)=3) AND ((tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IsActive)=Yes) AND 
(([tb200_IraDataIn].[tb200_Shovi]/[SubQuery1].[SumOftb200_Shovi])>0.1));
```

subquery (saved as SubQuery1):

```
SELECT tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IraAccDesc, tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IraAccNum, Sum(tb200_IraDataIn.tb200_Shovi) AS SumOftb200_Shovi
FROM tb206_IraAccount 
INNER JOIN tb200_IraDataIn ON tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IraAccNum = tb200_IraDataIn.tb200_accountNumber
WHERE (((tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IsActive)=Yes))
GROUP BY tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IraAccDesc, tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IraAccNum;
```

How can I put the sql statement of the sub-query inside the same Sql statement of the main query, unlike now?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you have a working query, why do you want to change it? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Actually, in MS Access saved queries tend to be more efficient than subqueries. See [Allen Browne's tips on optimization](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html).

Answer (score 0):

Nest between parentheses. Nothing else in the main query changes.

```
SELECT
...
FROM (SELECT tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IraAccDesc, tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IraAccNum, Sum(tb200_IraDataIn.tb200_Shovi) AS SumOftb200_Shovi
FROM tb206_IraAccount 
INNER JOIN tb200_IraDataIn ON tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IraAccNum = tb200_IraDataIn.tb200_accountNumber
WHERE (((tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IsActive)=Yes))
GROUP BY tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IraAccDesc, tb206_IraAccount.tb206_IraAccNum) AS SubQuery1
...
```